# How to write a plugin for Nutch 2.3

Tags: java, apache, plugins, nutch

I am using Nutch 2.3 version to crawl data. I have to add a plugin in Nutch. I have search from web. I have found some guide from web e.g. [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample). But it is for older version of Nutch 1.x.

How I'll do it please elaborate it as I am new in this field ?

Comment: https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-2.3/ check this, I once assigned a task to do so, but the requirements then changed and I couldn't do it, However this interface needs to be implemented if you want to implement your own plugin. And also to this : http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins

Comment: I have tried this but classes are different